# web-development: how to display an increasing number of messages?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to build a website that display changing text-messages.

The server gets the text-messages from a DB. 
I wanted to grab a chunck of msgs, shufle them and send them to the client to present each of them. When the client is done with the current chunck he asks the server for the next chunck.

can some one help me with client side psudou-code?
I though to use asp.net ans JS but I'm newbie to JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (based on your question) you want to periodically check the server for messages ? this will require you to communcate between the client and the server. The best method for doing this is [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

AJAX is a method of sending a query to the server and retrieving information back - you can then display the retrieved information to the user (the messages).

A good introduction to AJAX is here -> http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

To get the delay between requests you can use `setInterval` -> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Create a function in javascript to fetch and display the messages - then setup the `setInterval` function to call this method every x seconds / minutes as desired

Comment: how whould you display the messages with some delay between them?

Comment: Updated my answer - `setInterval()` function in Javascript gives you this ability

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean when you say 'when the client is done'. Do you mean a user physically asks for more messages by clicking on a button? Or is it that the user scrolls/clicks through the messages, and then the client-side software asks for more when they've all been seen?